# How to return current ID on .on(click) inside $.each function - jQuery

Tags: jquery, tippyjs

In a jQuery '$(document).unbind().on('click',..' function inside a '$.each(arr, function(index, val) {' I am trying to get the current ID of the array, which returns correct inside the $.each, but will only return the last ID inside the '.on('click')'

I have tried to retrive the ID other ways aswell using data attribute with different variations of .closest and .parent, but has had no luck to get the ID returned correct.

In the below snippet I have made a minified structure of HTML and I have written comments to the jQuery what I have tried and what have been the outcome.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#MessageLink<%=objMessageCenterSender("
    SenderInitials ")%>").click(function() {
    $("#MessageInlineModal").hide();
    $("#MessagesSystemContainer").hide();
    $("#MessagesSpecificUserContainer").fadeIn("slow");

    $.post('includes/messagecenter_user_messages.asp', {
      "SenderID": <%=objMessageCenterSender("SenderID")%>,
      "SenderInitials": '<%=LCase(objMessageCenterSender("SenderInitials"))%>',
      "ReceiverInitials": '<%=LCase(Session("ADsAMAccountName"))%>'
    }, function(json) {

      $('#MessagesSpecificUser').html(json.UserMessageBody);

      console.log(json.MessageIDArray) // This returns : [388, 387, 382, 381]

      var arr = JSON.parse(json.MessageIDArray);
      $.each(arr, function(index, val) {

        console.log(val) // Returns correct indexed ID i.e 387

        function startCount() {
          $('.count' + val).data('initial', new Date().getTime() - ($('.count' + val).data('secs') || 0) * 1000);
          setInterval(function() {
            $('.count' + val).text(function() {
              const diff = new Date().getTime() - $(this).data('initial');
              if (Math.floor(diff / (24 * 3600000)) > 0) {
                return Math.floor(diff / (24 * 3600000)) + ' dage'; // more than 1 day
              } else if (Math.floor(diff / 3600000) > 0) {
                return Math.floor(diff / 3600000) + ' timer'; // more than 1 hour
              } else if (Math.floor(diff / 60000) > 0) {
                return Math.floor(diff / 60000) + ' minuter'; // more than 1 minute
              } else {
                return Math.floor(diff / 1000) + ' sekunder';
              }
            })
          }, 1000);
        }
        startCount()

        tippy('#ReactionBar' + val, {
          a11y: true,
          role: 'tooltip',
          allowHTML: true,
          animation: 'perspective-extreme',
          appendTo: () => document.body,
          arrow: true,
          arrowType: 'sharp',
          boundary: 'scrollParent',
          content: json.ReactionBarContent,
          delay: 0,
          offset: [0, 5],
          duration: [325, 275],
          hideOnClick: true,
          ignoreAttributes: false,
          inertia: false,
          interactive: true,
          interactiveBorder: 2,
          interactiveDebounce: 0,
          placement: 'top-end',
          popperOptions: {},
          showOnCreate: false,
          size: 'regular',
          target: '',
          theme: 'light',
          touch: true,
          trigger: 'mouseenter focus',
          triggerTarget: null,
          moveTransition: 'transform 0.2s ease-out',
        });

        $(document).unbind().on('click', '.messageemoji', function() {

          console.log(val) // This will only retur 381 no matter which element I clicked

          var emoji = $(this).data("emoji")

          // Since 'val' does not return correct here, I have experimentet
          // with adding a data-messageid attribute to the closest DIV that
          // holds Tippy 'ReactionBar + val' (See structure in HTML). But 
          // this gives me Undefined in all attempts .. i.e.:

          var messageid = $(this).closest('.messageemoji').data('messageid');
          var messageid2 = $(this).unbind().closest('div').data('messageid');
          var messageid3 = $(this).parent('div').data('messageid');
          var messageid4 = $(this).closest('div').data('messageid');

          console.log(messageid) // Returns Undefined
          console.log(messageid2) // Returns Undefined
          console.log(messageid3) // Returns Undefined
          console.log(messageid4) // Returns Undefined

          $.post("includes/update_messagecenter_emoji.asp", {
            "ReceiverID": <%=Session("LogedInUserID")%>,
            "MessageID": messageid,
            "Emoji": emoji
          });

        });

      });

    }, 'json');

  });
});
```

```html
// minified structure of Tippy JS Reactionbar:

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span><img data-emoji='smiling_face.gif' src='smiling_face.gif' class='messageemoji'></span></td>
      <td><span><img data-emoji='smiling_face.gif' src='winking_face.gif' class='messageemoji'></span></td>
      <td><span><img data-emoji='smiling_face.gif' src='beaming_face_with_smiling_eyes.gif' class='messageemoji'></span></td>
      ...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

// minified structure of #Reactionbar:

<div id='ReactionBar[i.e 387]' data-messageid='387' class='card'>
  <div class='card-body'>
    <span id='Reaction[i.e 387]'><img src='smiling_face.gif'>
</span>
    <div>Some text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE :** Content of json.ReactionBarContent:

```html
<table class='table table-borderless table-sm p-1 m-1' style='width: 140px;'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Smiler'><img data-emoji='smiling_face.gif' src='img/smileyani/smiling_face.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Blinker'><img data-emoji='winking_face.gif' src='img/smileyani/winking_face.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Griner'><img data-emoji='beaming_face_with_smiling_eyes.gif' src='img/smileyani/beaming_face_with_smiling_eyes.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='ROFL'><img data-emoji='rolling_on_the_floor_laughing.gif' src='img/smileyani/rolling_on_the_floor_laughing.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Gr&aelig;der'><img data-emoji='crying_face.gif' src='img/smileyani/crying_face.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='&nbsp;&nbsp;Like&nbsp;&nbsp;'><img data-emoji='thumbs_up.gif' src='img/smileyani/thumbs_up.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='&nbsp;&nbsp;Nej&nbsp;&nbsp;'><img data-emoji='thumbs_down.gif' src='img/smileyani/thumbs_down.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Bunke&nbsp;lort'><img data-emoji='pile_of_poo.gif' src='img/smileyani/pile_of_poo.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Aftale'><img data-emoji='handshake.gif' src='img/smileyani/handshake.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Vinker'><img data-emoji='waving_hand.gif' src='img/smileyani/waving_hand.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Ikke&nbsp;snakke'><img data-emoji='speak_no_evil_monkey.gif' src='img/smileyani/speak_no_evil_monkey.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Ikke&nbsp;h&oslash;re'><img data-emoji='hear_no_evil_monkey.gif' src='img/smileyani/hear_no_evil_monkey.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Ikke&nbsp;se'><img data-emoji='see_no_evil_monkey.gif' src='img/smileyani/see_no_evil_monkey.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Stille'><img data-emoji='shushing_face.gif' src='img/smileyani/shushing_face.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Gaber'><img data-emoji='yawning_face.gif' src='img/smileyani/yawning_face.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='T&aelig;nker'><img data-emoji='thinking_face.gif' src='img/smileyani/thinking_face.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Dj&aelig;vel'><img data-emoji='smiling_face_with_horns.gif' src='img/smileyani/smiling_face_with_horns.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Mund&nbsp;lukket'><img data-emoji='zipper_mouth_face.gif' src='img/smileyani/zipper_mouth_face.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Svimmel'><img data-emoji='dizzy_face.gif' src='img/smileyani/dizzy_face.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Tr&aelig;t'><img data-emoji='sleeping_face.gif' src='img/smileyani/sleeping_face.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Overrasket'><img data-emoji='hushed_face.gif' src='img/smileyani/hushed_face.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Ruller&nbsp;&oslash;jne'><img data-emoji='face_with_rolling_eyes.gif' src='img/smileyani/face_with_rolling_eyes.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Sk&oslash;r'><img data-emoji='zany_face.gif' src='img/smileyani/zany_face.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Op&nbsp;Ned'><img data-emoji='upside_down_face.gif' src='img/smileyani/upside_down_face.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Opkast'><img data-emoji='face_vomiting.gif' src='img/smileyani/face_vomiting.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='&nbsp;Sur&nbsp;'><img data-emoji='frowning_face.gif' src='img/smileyani/frowning_face.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Kedeligt'><img data-emoji='unamused_face.gif' src='img/smileyani/unamused_face.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Rasende'><img data-emoji='face_with_symbols_on_mouth.gif' src='img/smileyani/face_with_symbols_on_mouth.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Overraket'><img data-emoji='flushed_face.gif' src='img/smileyani/flushed_face.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Frygt'><img data-emoji='face_screaming_in_fear.gif' src='img/smileyani/face_screaming_in_fear.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Krammer'><img data-emoji='hugging_face.gif' src='img/smileyani/hugging_face.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Fest'><img data-emoji='partying_face.gif' src='img/smileyani/partying_face.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Cool'><img data-emoji='smiling_face_with_sunglasses.gif' src='img/smileyani/smiling_face_with_sunglasses.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Kloge&nbsp;&aring;ge'><img data-emoji='nerd_face.gif' src='img/smileyani/nerd_face.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Smigret'><img data-emoji='smiling_face_with_hearts.gif' src='img/smileyani/smiling_face_with_hearts.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Blinker&nbsp;med&nbsp;tunge'><img data-emoji='winking_face_with_tongue.gif' src='img/smileyani/winking_face_with_tongue.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Krammer'><img data-emoji='hugging_face.gif' src='img/smileyani/hugging_face.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Smiler'><img data-emoji='smiling_face.gif' src='img/smileyani/smiling_face.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Blinker'><img data-emoji='winking_face.gif' src='img/smileyani/winking_face.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Sk&aring;l'><img data-emoji='clinking_beer_mugs.gif' src='img/smileyani/clinking_beer_mugs.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Hjerte'><img data-emoji='sparkling_heart.gif' src='img/smileyani/sparkling_heart.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Brast&nbsp;hjerte'><img data-emoji='broken_heart.gif' src='img/smileyani/broken_heart.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='&nbsp;&nbsp;100%&nbsp;&nbsp;'><img data-emoji='hundred_points.gif' src='img/smileyani/hundred_points.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
      <td class='p-0 m-0'><span class='fa-tooltip' data-fa-tooltip='Tiden&nbsp;g&aring;r'><img data-emoji='clock.gif' src='img/smileyani/clock.gif' style='width: 24px; height: 24px; cursor: pointer;' class='messageemoji grow fa-shadow-sm'></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**What I have changed:**

```
    ...
     }
    startCount()
    
   json.ReactionBarContent = $(json.ReactionBarContent).attr("data-val",val)
    
    
      tippy('#ReactionBar' + val, {
        a11y: true,
        role: 'tooltip',
        ...
```

And then moved the click here:

```
    }, 'json');


   $(document).unbind().on('click', '.messageemoji', function(){                                                                
                                
    var val = $(this).closest("table")
    var emoji = $(this).data("emoji")

    console.log( val )

    $.post( "includes/update_messagecenter_emoji.asp", {"ReceiverID": <%=Session("LogedInUserID")%>,"MessageID": val ,"Emoji": emoji } );

  });                    
});
```

Comment: Problem is that your val is getting replaced in the click event every time you bind/unbind the click event. I can't see how you entire html is rendered, but you should bind the value of `val` somehow to objects with 'messageemoji'. But as i said, since I can't see the entire rendered html I can't give you a better answer

Comment: What does `json.ReactionBarContent` looks like?

Comment: Hi @CarstenLøvboAndersen .. unfortunately I cannot bind the ID to the Tippy JS Reactionbar (which is json.ReactionBarContent) since it will potentially make the json response huge the more messages the user gets.

Comment: If you could include what 1 `json.ReactionBarContent` would look like I could give you an example of modifying the content before using it in tippy. I suggest that you convert it and add an attribute in it.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I have just added the output of json.ReactionBarContent under UPDATE in my post  :-)

Comment: Try look at this fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/L9k14fzv/ So before you init tippy like `tippy('#ReactionBar' + val, {` you use the code from fiddle. Then move your document click event out and do like `var val = $(this).closest("table")`

Comment: The line from fiddle you need is like json.ReactionBarContent = $(json.ReactionBarContent).attr("data-val",val)

Comment: This looks really simple and at the same time really advanced @CarstenLøvboAndersen :-D .. I think this wil work, but at the moment it does not, I most oversee something .. 1:  The Tippy content displayed is only `[object object]`  ..  2: The output of console.log(json.ReactionBarContent) is : `S.fn.init [table.table.table-borderless.table-sm.p-1.m-1]
0: table.table.table-borderless.table-sm.p-1.m-1
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Object(0)`   .. am I missing something? (I have made a section to original post with my changes)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239116/discussion-between-carsten-lovbo-andersen-and-stig-kolbaek).

Comment: It's my mistake, `var val = $(this).closest("table")` should be `var val = $(this).closest("table").attr("data-val")`

Comment: Hi @CarstenLøvboAndersen .. have you had time to see my messages in the chat? :-)